How do I extract a dynamic number from a text file in bash?
I am looking to extract a dynamic port number from a text file and print it in to a new text file.
The surrounding text stays the same.
Currently I am using:

sed -n '89p' originalfile.txt | cut -c 16- > newfile.txt

Line 89 of originalfile.txt is:
Forwarded port 12345

and then newfile.txt only contains that 5 digit number.
This has been working, except some times the line number changes from 89 to something else, and I was looking for a more permanent solution?
Another piece of text in originalfile.txt is this, which may be better to use:
--> The port is 12345 and it will expire on 2024-08-28T23:50:18. <--


Use a suitable regular expression to match that line. What suitable is also depends on what it should not match. For example, if the word port only appears on that line, sed -n '/port/p' will have the same effect. Also have a look at awk which might be more applicable to your needs.

Do you also want a match in --> The port is 12345 ?

awk is perfectly capable of looking for patterns itself, so rather than using grep and awk, you can be a little more efficient and use just a single process (instead of requiring a superfluous grep) and also stop when you have found what you are looking for:
awk '/Forwarded/ { print $3; exit }' YOURFILE


I agree it doesn't always make much difference, but if you happen to be doing it (maybe in parallel) on lots of large files that have lots of other content, it's worth thinking about.

If the line number is not constant you should use a regular expression that matches the line of interest, instead of a line number. With any POSIX sed:
sed -n '/^Forwarded port [0-9][0-9]*$/p' originalfile.txt | cut -c 16- > newfile.txt

The -n option suppresses the default output of all lines; the p (print) command prints only lines matching the ^Forwarded port [0-9][0-9]*$ regular expression:

^: beginning of line,
Forwarded port : literal,
[0-9]: a digit,
[0-9]*: zero or more other digits,
$: end of line.

But you don't need cut here, sed can also extract the port number:
sed -n 's/^Forwarded port \([0-9][0-9]*\)$/\1/p' originalfile.txt > newfile.txt

s/regex/rep/modifiers is the substitute command that replaces regular expression regex with replacement expression rep. Its p modifier prints the result if and only if there was a match. \(...\) is a capture group that you can replay in the replacement expression where \1 stands for the first capture group (\2 for the second...).
Note: with GNU sed and other advanced sed you can simplify a bit:
sed -nE 's/^Forwarded port ([0-9]+)$/\1/p' originalfile.txt > newfile.txt

-E enables extended regular expressions where there is no need to escape parentheses with backslashes and + means "one or more".
Note that, depending on your locale, the [0-9] bracket expression could match more characters than the 10 ASCII digits. If you need to be portable across locales you can replace [0-9] with [0123456789], or specify the C locale:
LC_ALL=C sed ...

